# Connect to Data Using Command Text in Word (Like you can in Excel)

Tags: sql-server, ms-word, odbc, database-connection

I am trying to mail merge letters (many different Word files with many different letters) with data that is supplied by SQL queries written on the fly using our company's database.

For example, in Excel, I can use a ODBC database connection and then specify the SQL "command text" in the properties of that database connection to create queries on the fly for the file I am working in at the moment.

I just create queries in SSMS and then paste them into the "command text" in the properties of the connection created in Excel.

I use the same connection for many Excel files, but different command text depending on the data needed in each specific Excel file table.

I just can't figure out how to do something similar in Word so I can use custom SQL queries that provide the data I need for mail merging.

The SQL queries need to be always using data that are live from the database when the mail merge occurs.  They cannot be a static queries since these letters contain data that change from day to day (in the database) for the recipients of the letters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mailmerges use whatever data are current. If you need to apply various conditions, look under Mailings|Edit Recipient List - where you'll also find sorting and filtering options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent place in Word that lets you specify an SQL query. Word's whole approach to queries is "choose a table/view/query in one dialog, then specify columns, some basic sorting and filtering in the Edit Recipient List dialog box and I will build the query".

So you either need to use code to connect Word to the data (basically you would call ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource with the appropriate parameters), or you need to get your data via an intermediary so that you don't have to provide the detailed query to Word at all.

For example, if you have the necessary SQL Server permissions, you might be able to take the query you developed in SMSS and use it to create a View, which you then use as the Data Source. (If you don't need to be able to re-use these data sources or keep them for documentation purposes, you could just have one such View that you recreate for each merge you need.) IMO if you can make that work it's probably the simplest solution to this problem.

Or perhaps you could use Excel as an intermediate data source (you create or re-use a worksheet, create/modify its connection/query as you are doing already), get the data, save the workbook and use that as your data source. You might have to deal with some limitations, e.g. Word can only retrieve 255 or 256 columns from an Excel Data Source, Word can have problems dealing with mixed data types in Excel columns, and so on).

For small amounts of data you could even use a Word document containing a `{ DATABASE }` field as an intermediate data source. For example, if you have a .odc with the relevant connection info. called `c:\odcs\myodc.odc` and you have a query `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield < 1000` you would need a field something like this:

```
{ DATABASE \d "c:\\odcs\\myodc.odc" \s "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE myfield < 1000" }
```

(You insert the special field brace pair {  } using ctrl-F9 on WIndows Word, and type everything else. It's generally best to save your document before executing the field. Execute by selecting the field and pressing F9, and use Alt-F9 to toggle between field code and field results.)

I say "small" because otherwise Word is quite likely to hang if the query retrieves a large number of rows, and retrieving a large number of columns might cause other problems.

But there is a problem with this. Word is quite picky about query syntax, so you can't just use any old query that would work fine in SSMS in either a Database field or in a call to .OpenDataSource. For example, in order to get the above query to work in the DATABASE field, I had to change it to

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mytable.myfield < 1000
```

Sometimes Word insists that you wrap table names in delimiters (say, "" or []) or that you alias a table name. Also, OpenDataSource and the DATABASE field both limit the number of characters in the Query. For OpenDataSource there's an absolute maximum of 511 or 512 characters, and for anything over 255 characters you have to split the query string in two.

All of that stuff is why I actually think you would be better off creating a View and using that, if you can make that work.

If you want to use the OpenDataSource approach, you're going to have to write some VBA anyway, so the simplest way to do that is to create a VBA macro with an OpenDataSource statement in it, perhaps stored in WOrd's Normal template. Then, to set up your data source, you open your Mail Merge Main Document so it's the "ActiveDocument" in Word, you open the VB Editor, open up that macro, copy/paste in your SQL text and modify it as necessary to comply with Word's 
SQL syntax requirements. Then run it.

e.g. for queries up to 255 characters long your macro could look like this:

```
Sub ConnectToDataSource()
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
  Name:="the full path and file name of a suitable .odc file" , _
  SQLStatement:="the sql statement"
End Sub
```

The .odc would need to contain the connection information. Alternatively, you can use a blank .odc and put the connection info in the call:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
  Name:="the full path and file name of a suitable .odc file" , _
  Connection:="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI; etc.", _
  SQLStatement:="the sql statement"
```

For longer queries you would need

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
  Name:="the full path and file name of a suitable .odc file" , _
  SQLStatement:="part 1 of the SQL query", _
  SQLStatement1:="part 2 of the SQL query"
```

(When you do that, Word concatenates the two pieces of query with no spaces so if for example you use

```
  SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM mytable", _
  SQLStatement1:="WHERE myfield < 10"
```

your query will actually be

```
SELECT * FROM mytableWHERE myfield < 10
```

Going back to my sample query, I had to modify it again to use it in OpenDataSource, which wanted this syntax:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
  Name:="the full path and file name of a suitable .odc file" , _
  SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM ""ktd1"" WHERE k < 10"
```

One other problem you may have with a Word connection and not with an Excel connection is that if you connect using an ODBC driver, Unicode format text field content does not reach Word. You to use an OLE DB provider to avoid that.

Finally, when you make a new connection in Word to a database such as SQL Server, Word generates a .odc file that contains the connection and table information. Although it looks as if this is a general-purpose facility that would enable you to specify any query you like by modifying the `<odc:CommandText>` element value in there to contain your query (and perhaps modify the `<odc:CommandType>` to be "SQL" rather than "Table"), nothing I have ever tried actually works. In fact Word seems to ignore `<odc:CommandText>` and actually gets its table name from `<meta name=Table content=thetablename>` earlier in the file. So you can't just edit the .odc file to achieve your objective.

Comment: Thank you so much Snarky!  This appears to be an amazing answer with lots of great options.  I'm going to dive into these this weekend and figure out which one will work best.  I do believe one of them will definitely work so I want to go ahead and accept your answer so it's not out there hanging!